Apache:Drill cannot create view
I'm new to Apache Drill. I tried to put files from both workspaces in one view to see the convenience query, but there was an error.
I tried to use SQL statements to build views to integrate data from two workspaces into one view, the statement is as follows:
CREATE VIEW data_access.all_channels_view AS (
SELECT
     columns[0] as channel_number,
     columns[1] as stimestamp,
     columns[2] as svalue,
     'channel_0' as channel
FROM
     data_access.channel_0.`*.txt`
UNION ALL
SELECT
     columns[0] as channel_number,
     columns[1] as stimestamp,
     columns[2] as svalue,
     'channel_1' as channel
FROM
     data_access.channel_1.`*.txt`);

The error is:
Error: VALIDATION ERROR: Unable to create or drop objects. Schema [data_access] is immutable.

I guarantee that all of my workspaces are set up to be writable, as follows:
{
  "type": "file",
  "connection": "file:///",
  "workspaces": {
    "channel_0": {
      "location": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\DataFiles\\Channel_0",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": true
    },
    "channel_1": {
      "location": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\DataFiles\\Channel_1",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": true
    }
  },
  "formats": {
    "json": {
      "type": "json",
      "extensions": [
        "json"
      ]
    },
    "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "txt"
      ],
      "lineDelimiter": "\n",
      "fieldDelimiter": ",",
      "quote": "\"",
      "escape": "\"",
      "comment": "#"
    },
    "parquet": {
      "type": "parquet"
    }
  },
  "authMode": "SHARED_USER",
  "enabled": true
}

I have checked a lot of information but it is not helpful. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

Try this -

The error message indicates that the schema data_access is immutable, which means you cannot create or drop objects (like views) in this schema.
Looking at your workspace configuration, I notice that you have defined workspaces channel_0 and channel_1, but not a workspace or schema named data_access.
To fix the issue, you need to create a writable workspace or schema named data_access. You can do this by adding a new workspace to your configuration file:

After channel_1 you add this in your configuration file
"data_access": {
  "location": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\DataFiles\\DataAccess",
  "writable": true,
  "defaultInputFormat": null,
  "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": true
}


data_access is the name of my custom storage plugin, which stores the contents of my json configuration file(I mentioned above).@Tiger Resource

Your view needs to be created in some workspace too, where its definition will be stored in a file. You could CREATE VIEW data_access.channel_0.all_channels_view, or you could put the view in another workspace entirely.
